# Visual Studio code keyboard shortcuts to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to use the **Visual Studio Code** key scheme in **Notepad++**.

I know that I can't have all functions like <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, but at least the rest like comment/uncomment; expand/collapse block...., and many other universal functions can be mapped to have the same keyboard scheme.

So how can I do this without changing each shortcut key by hand?

Comment: 3 years have passed. Have you found the answer?

Answer (score -6):

Use Extension named Notepad ++ Keymap.

[image]

Link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.notepadplusplus-keybindings

Comment: They want to do the opposite, have VS keymap in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes I'm also looking for the opposite namely transferring VSC key bindings to Notepad++. Any tips appreciated...

Comment: I'd like to have my Notepad++ set up this way too! (ie Ctrl+C, copy line; Alt+Down, move line down; etc). Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: I can't upvote since it doesn't answer the question but it was *this* answer I was actually looking for.  This is a top result for "vscode keyboard shortcuts like notepad++".  So thanks!